# How to start notebook from a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've installed Python 3.6 in my machine and created a virtual environment where i've installed some libraries I wanted.

I've also installed jupyter notebook via anaconda site.
Now, when I open Jupyter notebook from the virtual env I created in step 1, for some reason it looks like it is not really using this env. As i'm not able to access the libraries i instaled in virtualenv. whereas from command prompt inside that virtual env, i'm able to access.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you `activate` from command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I activated via command prompt, so it took me into virtual environment (basically it shows the virtual env name in brackets) and then i launched jupyter notebook from there in command prompt.

Comment: @Ravi you mention an "install of Python 3.6" with a virtual environment and then an anaconda install. The two installs of Python are not related and you cannot use libraries from the one in the other. Solving your issues  involves: locating both versions of Python and making sure that none is actived automatically in your terminal. Decide which one to choose and (ideally) remove the other one. Activate the chosen version and install the libraries there.

Comment: thankyou, it helps. I don't see a button to mark this 'answered'